# I am having trouble deploying a Node app to Heroku, where am I going wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I keep trying to push my code but hit a brick wall and have a page which gives me an application error and tells me to check the logs.

I am unsure of what to do next.

I can provide the git repo address if that helps.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to check for when deployment fails on Heroku.

Have you...

1. Made a **procfile** on the root folder? It's usually a simple one-line file that tells it to run the server.

   ```
   web: node server/server.js
   ```
2. Included necessary modules in your **package.json** file?
3. Does your server need to connect to a DB? If so, logs should tell you something like database connection failed.

Please refer to the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, will have a go now. Does a Procfile need a suffix at the end?

Comment: Nope, just Procfile - with no file extension.